# Just the last one relationship in doctrine .orm file is working

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to make some relationships in Doctrine

LancamentoConf.orm.yml:

```yaml
Amz\FinanceiroBundle\Entity\LancamentoConf:
  type: entity
  table: amz_financeiro_lancamento_conf
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    active:
      type: string
      length: 1
  ...
  manyToOne:
    conta:
      targetEntity: ContaConf
      inversedBy: contajoinlancamentoconf
      joinColumn:
        name: amz_financeiro_conta_conf_id
        referencedColumnName: id
  manyToOne:
    centrodecusto:
      targetEntity: Amz\AmzBundle\Entity\CentroDeCustoConf
      inversedBy: lancamentoconf
      joinColumn:
        name: amz_centro_de_custo_conf_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

ContaConf.orm.yml:

```yaml
Amz\FinanceiroBundle\Entity\ContaConf:
  type: entity
  table: amz_financeiro_conta_conf
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    active:
      type: string
      length: 1
  ...
  oneToMany:
    contajoinlancamentoconf:
      targetEntity: LancamentoConf
      mappedBy: lancamentoconf
```

But just "centrodecusto" relationship is working...

I noticed that just the last one relationship in LancamentoConf.orm.yml works. If I change the order ("centrodecusto" first and "conta" second), "centrodecusto" will work fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is duplicated manyToOne section, there should be only one definition and inside you could define several elements:

LancamentoConf.orm.yml:

```
Amz\FinanceiroBundle\Entity\LancamentoConf:
  type: entity
  table: amz_financeiro_lancamento_conf
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    active:
      type: string
      length: 1
  ...
  manyToOne:
    conta:
      targetEntity: ContaConf
      inversedBy: contajoinlancamentoconf
      joinColumn:
        name: amz_financeiro_conta_conf_id
        referencedColumnName: id
    centrodecusto:
      targetEntity: Amz\AmzBundle\Entity\CentroDeCustoConf
      inversedBy: lancamentoconf
      joinColumn:
        name: amz_centro_de_custo_conf_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```